# How to delete the rows using subquery - mysql

Tags: mysql

The following doesnt work in mysql, any alternate way:

```
DELETE  FROM _ResourceUsageData 
WHERE RowNo >
(SELECT MIN(RowNo) FROM 
_ResourceUsageData 
WHERE
ResourceInstanceStatus = 'Deleted');
```

Comment: @chanchal118 I don't think this is a duplicate, the question you link to is resolved by using the proper syntax and does contain the table being deleted from in the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

In Mysql you can't select from a table you are deleting from. But you can trick it with another subquery.

```
DELETE FROM _ResourceUsageData 
WHERE RowNo > 
(
    select * from 
    (
        SELECT MIN(RowNo) 
        FROM _ResourceUsageData 
        WHERE ResourceInstanceStatus = 'Deleted'
    ) x
)
```